# ArrayFormula for Earliest Date in each row

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet containing names and dates. I need to determine the date exactly five years after the earliest date listed for each name.

[Here is the data with names/info scrubbed, and the formulas as I have them currently.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/150-Xe7c3rCDgBVQtuZ3EasYLRMV7G1TXtIzDkoQ3bJo/edit?usp=sharing)

The only output I ultimately need is the Renewal Date (minimum date + 5 years). Is there a way to output that data to new rows without having to manually copy the format into column E in each new row?

Also, I'd prefer if it only outputs a Renewal Date if there is a date listed in each column. If a row is missing one (or more) dates, no Renewal Date should exist.

I have absolutely no formal Excel/Sheets training or experience, so any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, It's quiet long problem statement.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: and let me tell you what I have got you from this. Read the google sheet and get the renewal date of each employee and renewal date is `None` if row is have at least one date.

Comment: I've tried building an ArrayFormula to calculate the Earliest Date (similar to the formula in F1), but haven't had any luck. The Sheet I linked to is the closest I've managed to come. I don't have any formal Excel/Sheets training, so I'm way out of my depth here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I duplicated the sheet in your shared spreadsheet and entered in cell E1

```
={"Renewal Date";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIF(IF(B2:D<>"", ROW(B2:B)),ROW(B2:B))=3, EDATE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE( B2:D) , "Select "&"MIN(Col"&JOIN( ", MIN(Col",FILTER(ROW(A2:A)-1, A2:A<>"")&")"))), "Select Col2", 0),60),))}
```

See if that works for you?

Comment: This is really clever. I guess this method could be applied to other summary statistics per row, e.g. your previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366138/google-sheets-formula-arrayformula-to-apply-to-each-row except that the MMULT way was shorter in this particular case.

Comment: This is exactly the functionality I was going for, thank you so much. I understand some of what this formula is doing, but as I mentioned I'm way out of my element here. Time to do some more reading/playing around until I know how it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, ColumnE is not required and the Renewal Date may be calculated with:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(count(B2:D2)<>3,"",edate(MIN(B2:D2),60)))
```

though the `Arrayformula` above is not achieving anything useful - the formula still has to be copied down (from Row2).

Comment: Is there any way to achieve that output without needing to copy down the formula? That's ultimately what I'm looking for. Sorry if I didn't communicate that well, I'll try to edit my post to better reflect what I'm after.